# How can I enter the jewel shop in Jailbreak without a keycard?

Tags: roblox

There is a white X next to the door. I punched it, but it still didn't work. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the Jewelry Store is **open** (the lights are on and the 'closed' sign is off) walk up to one of the two 'X's on the ground (it is more likely that the X with the most players on it will work).

A laser cutter will appear and begin to slice through the glass, which takes about two seconds. After a short gap appears, crawl through the slot and enter the Store.